# Bootstrap set active class for multilevel menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have multilevel menu as below:

```html
<li><a id="Default" href="Default.aspx">Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a id="Readings" href="#">Readings<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
  <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
    <li><a id="Reading-Dip" href="Readings.aspx?Mode=Dip">Dip</a></li>
    <li><a id="Reading-Dispenser" href="Readings.aspx?Mode=Dispenser">Dispenser</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a id="Transactions" href="#"></i>Transactions<spanclass="fa arrow"></span></a>
<ul class="nav nav-second-level">
  <li><a id="Transactions-1" href="Transactions.aspx?1">Second Level Link</a </li>
    <li><a id="Transactions-2" href="Transactions.aspx?2">Second Level Link</a> </li>
    <li><a id="Transactions-3" href="Transactions.aspx?3">Second Level Link<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
      <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
        <li><a id="Transactions-3-1" href="Transactions.aspx?3-1">Third Level Link</a> </li>
        <li><a id="Transactions-3-2" href="Transactions.aspx?3-2">Third Level Link</a> </li>
        <li><a id="Transactions-3-3" href="Transactions.aspx?3-3">Third Level Link</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

I need to set `active-menu` class on `li` if it matches the url. It's working fine for the `li` which is clicked. In the case of a multilevel `ul` I need to set the parent li also.

Here is the current jQuery function which I have written:

```
var url = window.location;
$('ul.nav a').filter(function () {
   return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active-menu');
```

**Example:** If I select Transactions-3-1, then I need to set the `active` class on all of the following elements:

- Transactions-3-1
- Transactions-3
- Transactions

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`parents([selector])`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to find all of an element's ancestors that match a selector, in your case you can match all `li` ancestors using:

```
var url = window.location;
$('ul.nav a').filter(function () {
   return this.href == url;
}).parents('li').addClass('active-menu');
```